# Excepciones con pilas en Java

Tags: java, excepciones, pilas

Tengo una duda con el siguiente código. No consigo obtener el resultado.
Al ejecutar la clase `PruebaPilaVacia` debería lanzar una excepción si la pila esta vacía. En la clase `PruebaMax` debería obtener los elementos de la pila y su número más alto.

Cuando lo ejecuto me da una número negativo, pero no consigo el resultado que necesito.

**Clase Pilas:**

```
public class Pilas {

    public static int max(Pila pila) throws isEmpty {
        int max = (int) Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        if (pila.esVacia()) {
            throw new isEmpty("La pila está vacia");
        }
        else {
            return max;
        }
    } 
}
```

**Clase PruebaPilaVacia:**

```
public class PruebaPilaVacia {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Pila pila = new PilaEnlazada();

        try {
            System.out.println(pila);
            System.out.println(Pilas.max(pila));
        } catch (OperacionIncorrecta e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Clase PruebaMax:**

```
public class PruebaMax {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Pila pila = new PilaEnlazada();     
        pila.apilar(9);
        pila.apilar(-3);
        pila.apilar(23);
        pila.apilar(-5);

        try {
            System.out.println(pila);
            System.out.println(Pilas.max(pila));
            System.out.println(pila);
        } catch (OperacionIncorrecta e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Clase Pila:**

```
public interface Pila {

    public void apilar(Object elemento);

    public void desapilar();

    public Object cima();
    
    public boolean esVacia();
}
```

**Clase PilaEnlazada:**

```
public class PilaEnlazada implements Pila {

    private Nodo cima;
    
    public PilaEnlazada() {
        cima = null;
    }

    public void apilar(Object elemento) {
        Nodo nodo = new Nodo(elemento);
        nodo.setEnlace(cima);
        cima = nodo;
    }

    public void desapilar() throws DesbordamientoInferior {
        if (esVacia()) {
            throw new DesbordamientoInferior("Imposible desapilar");
        }
        cima = cima.getEnlace();
    }

    public Object cima() throws DesbordamientoInferior {
        if (esVacia()) {
            throw new DesbordamientoInferior("Imposible consultar la cima");
        }
        return cima.getElemento();
    }

    public boolean esVacia() {
        return (cima == null);
    }
}
```

He añadido la clase `Pila` y `PilaEnlazada`. No consigo que lance la excepción al encontrar la pila vacía. Agradecería si me indicaran donde están los errores.

Comment: Agrega el código de la clase PilaEnlazada.

Comment: Hola. Podés subir la implementación del método apilar?

Comment: Edito la pregunta y agrego el código Pila y PilaEnlazada.

Comment: El método max que se supone que es el que debería lanzar la excepción, lanza una excepción de tipo isEmpty, pero tu estás capturando una excepción de tipo OperacionIncorrecta. Para que esto te funcione o capturas isEmpty en lugar de OperacionIncorrecta, o haces que lance OperacionIncorrecta en max, o te aseguras que la excepción isEmpty herede de OperacionIncorrecta.

Comment: Hola, no acabo entenderlo. Podrías editarme el código para verlo mejor?

Comment: Falta el código de la clase `Nodo`, para saber cómo se establecen los enlaces, sobre todo cuando la pila está vacía y apilamos elementos.

Comment: También, la excepción `isEmpty` se salta las convenciones de nombrado de Java. Todas las clases que definas deben empezar por mayúscula, siguiendo el _Pascal Case_. Además, en el caso de las excepciones, considera refactorizar el nombre de la clase. El identificador `isEmpty` sigue las convenciones para ser método, pero no para ser clase. Una clase no debería empezar por la palabra `is`. Una sugerencia sería `EmptyStackException`, o en español, `ExcepcionPilaVacia`, así quedaría `throw new ExcepcionPilaVacia();`.

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que el resultado esperado es que PruebaMax imprima 23 en lugar de Integer.MIN_VALUE que es lo que hace tu implementación cuando la lista no está vacia.

Para simplificar la implementación correcta de `Pilas.max(pila)` voy a cambiar levemente tu interfaz e implementación de Pila. Voy a hacer que sea específica para enteros y que desapilar devuelva el valor retirado de la pila (es el comportamiento habitual de esta estructura de datos):

```java
public interface Pila {

    public void apilar(Integer elemento);

    public Integer desapilar() throws DesbordamientoInferior;

    public Integer cima() throws DesbordamientoInferior ;

    public boolean esVacia();

}
```

Entonces la implementación `PilaEnlazada` quedaría:

```java
public class PilaEnlazada implements Pila {

    private Nodo cima;

    public PilaEnlazada() {
        cima = null;
    }

    public void apilar(Integer elemento) {
        Nodo nodo = new Nodo(elemento);
        nodo.setEnlace(cima);
        cima = nodo;
    }

    public Integer desapilar() throws DesbordamientoInferior {
        if (esVacia()) {
            throw new DesbordamientoInferior("Imposible desapilar");
        }
        Integer desapilado = cima.getElemento();
        cima = cima.getEnlace();
        return desapilado;
    }

    public Integer cima() throws DesbordamientoInferior {
        if (esVacia()) {
            throw new DesbordamientoInferior("Imposible consultar la cima");
        }
        return cima.getElemento();
    }

    public boolean esVacia() {
        return (cima == null);
    }
}
```

Un `Nodo` sería simplemente:

```java
public class Nodo {

    private Integer elemento;

    private Nodo enlace;

    public Nodo(Integer elemento) {
        this.elemento = elemento;
    }

    public Integer getElemento() {
        return elemento;
    }

    public void setEnlace(Nodo nodo) {
        this.enlace = nodo;
    }

    public Nodo getEnlace() {
        return enlace;
    }
}
```

Entonces la implementación de `Pilas.max(pila)` quedaría (notar que estoy tomando la recomendación de @Eequiis al renombrar tu excepción isEmpty):

```java
public class Pilas {

    public static int max(Pila pila) throws ExcepcionPilaVacia, DesbordamientoInferior {
        if (pila.esVacia()) {
            throw new ExcepcionPilaVacia("La pila está vacia");
        }
        return max(pila, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    }

    private static int max (Pila pila, int temp) throws DesbordamientoInferior {
        if (pila.esVacia())
            return temp;

        return max(pila, Integer.max(temp, pila.desapilar());
    }
}
```

El método privado auxiliar se llama recursivamente hasta que la pila esté vacía buscando el máximo.
Entonces `PruebaPilaVacia` devuelve:

```bash
PilaEnlazada@6f2b958e
ExcepcionPilaVacia: La pila está vacia
        at Pilas.max(Pilas.java:5)
        at PruebaPilaVacia.main(PruebaPilaVacia.java:9)
```

Y `PruebaMax`:

```bash
PilaEnlazada@1eb44e46
23
PilaEnlazada@1eb44e46
```